# Envio de parámetros de asp classic a asp classic

Tags: javascript, jquery, ms-access, asp

Tengo este codigo para abrir una ventana emergente que tiene una consulta dentro, enviando los parámetros necesarios para que la consulta funcione.. pero solo sé mandar un parámetro, como puedo mandar ambos? Lo intenté así, pero me sale el error de la foto

```
  function actualizaRiesgo(dni,fecha)
    {
    
     window.open('mostrar_detalle.asp?Dni=' + dni +'mostrar_detalle.asp?Fecha='+fecha,"NewWindow","toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes,menubar=no,resizable=no,copyhistory=no,height=610,width=800,top=40,left=40");   
    }       
         $('#table_detalle').on('click','.ver',function(){ 
           id=$(this).val();
           dni=$("#numero"+id).text();
           fecha=$("#fecha"+id).text();

           alert(dni);
           actualizaRiesgo(dni,fecha);
        });
```

[image: Este es el error que marca, ya que no sé como mandar ambos parámetros]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo manda los parámetros separados por un "&"

window.open('mostrar_detalle.asp?Dni=' + dni +'&Fecha='+fecha)

Comment: Gracias en serio!!